# Need to get name and age from the user in a specific format

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the specific output of

```
What is your name?
What is your age?
Hello, Mr. Alex Whatmore (35)!
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>


int main()
{ 
  string name;
  int age;

  cout<<"What is your name?";
  cin>>name;
  cout<<"What is your age?";
  cin>>age;
  cout<<"Hello,"<<name;
  cout<<age;
  cout<<"!";
return 0;
}
```

How could I put the numbers in brackets or how could I allow the user to input their first and last name?

Comment: `std::cout << "(" << age << ")!";`

Comment: Does your code not already allow the user to input their first and last name?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you ask your user for input, expect him or her to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
#include <ciso646>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  int         age;

  std::cout << "What is your name? ";
  getline( std::cin, name );

  std::cout << "What is your age? ";
  std::cin >> age;
  std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

  if (!std::cin or name.empty() or (age < 0) or ...)
  {
    complain about bad input
  }

  std::cout << "Hello " << name << " (" << age << ")!\n";
}
```

For homework assignments you can often assume that all input will be correct and leave off any checks.

- `!std::cin` will be true if the user tried to input anything but a valid integer for `age`, or if EOF was reached before all your inputs were complete.
- `name.empty()` doesn’t preclude the user from entering a bunch of spaces or dashes or anything weird for his name.
  You don’t need to care for a homework solution, but [Patrick McKenzie’s *Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names*](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) should be required reading for anyone serious about dealing with identifying people with computer systems.
- Obviously, people cannot be younger than zero years old.
- Et cetera.

The `numeric_limits` thing is obnoxiously verbose, but it is how C++ expects you to skip to NL. A more correct way would be to get input as a `string` and then attempt to convert the *entire* string to `int` and complain on failure. The exampled method lets the user enter any random stuff after a valid integer (which we just ignore with the `cin.ignore(...)`).

Again, for a simple homework, I’d let it slide.

Comment: that was lots of help thank you so much and for the thorough explanation

Comment: You should really validate every input, e.g. `if (!getline( std::cin, name )) { /* handle error */ }` and `if (!(std::cin >> age)) { /* handle error */ }`. Otherwise you blindly assume the input and numeric conversion succeed. You do validate `name` and `age` after all the input is taken. It's up to you where you do it, but ensure you don't attempt to make use of the variables filled until that is complete.

Comment: This example properly validates all input given a C++ program. It is my personal opinion that all input should be rigorously checked and sanitized. _**But**_ many homework assignments are explicit about input always being correct. A correct input precondition precludes need to verify.